# node-webkit Error: please install sqlite3 package manually

Tags: node.js, sqlite, node-webkit, sequelize.js

I'm working with `node-webkit`, `Sequelize` and `sqlite3`. Node runs the app with no problems, but when I run it from node-webkit it throws me this Error

```
"Uncaught Error: The dialect sqlite is not supported. (Error: Please install sqlite3 package manually)", source: /Users/mariowise/projects/node-webkit/requies-pos/node_modules/sequelize/lib/sequelize.js (176)
```

This are my dependencies

```
"dependencies": {
    "express": "~4.2.0",
    "static-favicon": "~1.0.0",
    "morgan": "~1.0.0",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.0.1",
    "body-parser": "~1.0.0",
    "debug": "~0.7.4",
    "jade": "~1.3.0",
    "nunjucks": "^1.0.5",
    "sqlite3": "~2.1.19",
    "config": "0.4.33",
    "sequelize": "~2.0.0-rc1",
    "sequelize-sqlite": "~1.7.0"
}
```

Comment: Hmm, strange, i'm not familiar with node-webkit but sequelize just require's sqlite so it uses the regular npm lookup.

You can remove sequelize-sqlite as a dependency by the way, just use sequelize and sqlite3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per the `sqlite3` module documentation, it looks like you'll need to build a node-webkit specific version of sqlite3 from source rather than relying on the version direct from npm:

https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3#building-for-node-webkit

Comment: If helps someone, this worked for me with `node@0.12.3`. Some how i've installed `node@0.12.0-alpha2` and it was not working. So there you go. Sorry the late validation, but just today I had time to test this. Thank you very much Jeff.